# How to add SCNNode of scene to other SCNScene

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I have one scene file in project which contains `plane node` `text node` in it. I have another `scene` file in project. where I wanted to place this plane node and text node with text node.

I am doing following code to access the node and place it but it's not adding properly on second tap event it's getting crashed.

```
   lazy var hotspotScene : SCNScene = {
         return SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/hotspot.scn")!
    }()


    let dummyNode = hotspotScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Hotspot", recursively: false)
    dummyNode?.position = result.worldCoordinates

    var hotspotNode : SCNNode?

    self.hotspotScene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (node, _) in
        if node.name == "plane" {
            hotspotNode = node
            print("found")

        }
    }


    hotspotNode?.name = String(arc4random())

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        hotspotNode!.position = result.worldCoordinates
        parentNode?.addChildNode(hotspotNode!)
    }
```

Error I am getting is :=

Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Scene Structure :

[image]

Actually I wanted following result :

[image]

Comment: Please provide more information about error during crash

Comment: @SergeyDi Error is about unwrapping optional value 'nil'

Comment: At what string you got the error?

Comment: hotspotNode!.position = result.worldCoordinates

Comment: Do you see result of: `print("found")` ?

Comment: No I am not getting found printed

Comment: Add screenshot of structure of the "art.scnassets/hotspot.scn"

Comment: @SergeyDi Added please check

Comment: @SergeyDi I found the solution. It was happening because I declared `hotspotScene` globally.